# Calculated column DAX - duration between dates with exclusions

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to calculate duration between two dates (with time) in my fact table. However there is a specific date&time, which I want to exclude in calculation e.g. 1:30AM Saturday - 4:30PM Monday.
For example:

| ID | StartDate | EndDate | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/1/2020 4:00PM | 12/4/2020 9:04AM | 2.71 |
| 2 | 11/29/2020 11:48AM | 12/1/2020 9:53AM | 0.72 |
| 3 | 11/30/2020 10:36AM | 12/1/2020 2:06PM | 0.9 |
| 4 | 12/2/2020 6:56AM | 12/3/2020 2:36PM | 1.32 |

I am not really sure how to solve this so I'll be grateful for help.

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Calculating-day-time-difference/td-p/59601  check if this helps

Comment: hi @Martino1994, in order get others to help, do you mind include more detail about your tech stack in the question?

Comment: Hi @Steven.Xi - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Martino1994 for example, what language (or database etc)...

Comment: I think this is similar to calculating Working Hours problem. Googling this may help.